# Deleting saved failed attempts of the non existing users when throttling login

Tags: php, mysql, security, throttling

Throttling the login,

Is it necessary that the failed attempts of a non existing user be inserted into the database?
If no action is taken cant someone guess the existing usernames in the database when throttling takes place for them and not the non existing ones, isn't this a security risk?

If it is necessary, how should I handle deleting them when the risk is lower?

```
//If the username does not exist do the below:

<?php 
    $stmt= $conn->prepare('SELECT * from failed_logins WHERE name="'.$_SESSION["Name"].'"');
    $stmt->bindParam(1, $name);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    while($row = $stmt->fetch()) {  
        $attempted = $row['attempted'];
    }
    $atime = strtotime($attempted);
    $current = time();
    if(($current-$atime) > 1500) { 
        $del= $conn->query("DELETE FROM failed_logins WHERE name = '".$_SESSION['Name']."'");
        $del->execute();
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the security standpoint, you should absolutely limit the number of failed login attempts per user. If you do not, you are seriously exposing your website to [brute-force attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brute-force_attack). For instance, after  after 3 failed login attempts, lock the user out for  24 hours based on their IP address.

I would not delete any data related to failed login attempts for the sake of *forensic investigation* you may perform periodically each 6 months, for example.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but isnt keeping all the failed login data in the database a problem, I am not an expert but too many failed attempts saved in the database would cost me my system, database and other things wouldnt it?

Comment: No, saving such data won't harm you in anyway as long as you sanitize all your data at output. It will be interesting to save those failed attempts in order to see how attackers behave. But you still have the option to  delete it whenever you judge it is no longer useful for you.